# Place sign on documents without opening documents using DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to develop API for signing documents by DocuSign. Is it possible in DocuSign to place a digital signature on documents without opening documents? For example: In my site client see a list of documents on a page, now client does not want to open documents one by one and sign each document. Instead of this he just clicks SIGN button on my website and all documents signed in back end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place signature on each document, you cannot have documents signed in backend then their will be no auditing that who actually signed the document and can lead to forgery so DocuSign does not allow this to happen.